# Size limit reached in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, aws-lambda, servicebus

I want to send data from AWS Lambda to Azure Service Bus Queue. Below is my attempt.

```
var azure = require("azure");

function test() {
  var serviceBusService = azure.createServiceBusService(
    "URL"
  );
  var message = {
    body: "Test message",
    customProperties: {
      testproperty: "TestValue"
    }
  };
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    serviceBusService.sendQueueMessage("myqueue", message, function(error) {
      if (!error) {
        console.log("message sent");
      }
    });
  }
}

test();
```

And it works fine in my local system

**What I want** - I want to put this code in AWS Lambda.

**Error** - When I upload it to Lambda I get error as `"Could not find azure package"`.

Solution Attempted - I zipped my local folder container **"node-modules"** which has **azure package** and zipped it to upload but I am getting size Limit reached for Lambda exception as zip file is greater than 50 MB (lambda limit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [azure](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure) NPM package is a) deprecated and b) a rollup of all features so it's much larger than you strictly need. If you really want to continue to use this then consider using a subset of the package, specifically `azure-arm-*` or `azure-*`.

You should consider moving to the [newer SDK](https://github.com/azure/azure-sdk-for-node#announcing-the-new-azure-sdk-for-javascript), specifically the [azure-arm-sb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-arm-sb) ServiceBus package.  Note that it too will be deprecated next year, when MS migrates it fully to TypeScript.